# Convert a data frame to a data.table without copy

Tags: r, dataframe, reference, data.table

I have a large data frame (in the order of several GB) that I'd like to convert to a `data.table`. Using `as.data.table` creates a copy of the data frame, which means I need available memory to be at least twice the size of the data. Is there a way to do the conversion without a copy?

Here's a simple example to demonstrate:

```
library(data.table)
N <- 1e6
K <- 1e2
data <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), K))

gc(reset=TRUE)
tracemem(data)
data <- as.data.table(data)
gc()
```

With output:

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.8.10  For help type: help("data.table")
N <- 1e6
K <- 1e2
data <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), K))

gc(reset=TRUE)
# used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used  (Mb)
# Ncells    303759  16.3     597831   32.0    303759  16.3
# Vcells 100442572 766.4  402928632 3074.2 100442572 766.4
tracemem(data)
# [1] "<0x363fda0>"
data <- as.data.table(data)
# tracemem[0x363fda0 -> 0x31e4260]: copy as.data.table.data.frame as.data.table 
gc()
# used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
# Ncells    304519  16.3     597831   32.0    306162   16.4
# Vcells 100444242 766.4  322342905 2459.3 200933219 1533.0
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is available from [v1.9.0+](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?root=datatable&view=log):

> o Following [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy/20346697#20346697), a function `setDT` is now implemented that takes a `list` (named and/or unnamed), `data.frame` (or `data.table`) as input and returns the same object as a `data.table` **by reference** (without any copy). See `?setDT` examples for more.

This is in accordance with `data.table` naming convention - all `set*` functions modifies by reference. `:=` is the only other that also modifies by reference.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.0+
setDT(data) # converts data which is a data.frame to data.table *by reference*
```

---

See history for older (now outdated) answers.

Comment: @Arun: Thanks for a detailed answer. I was actually asking how to convert a data frame to a data.table, but was sloppy in creating the toy example, I'll update my question to make it a data frame. Will the same idea then work for a data frame, e.g., getting rid of the first two setattr since a data frame already has these and keeping the rest?

Comment: @YT, if you mean getting a "data.frame" to a "data.table", then of course what you say is right. If you mean list of data.frames, then you'll have to bind them (column or row-wise) before to set the class and allocate.

Comment: @Arun, I meant the former, a single data frame to a data.table, I edited the question to hopefully better reflect it. Thanks again for a clever solution, I can accept the answer as is or wait if you'd like to edit it to match the revised question.

Comment: what exactly does the `settruelength` do?

Comment: eddi, `settruelength` just does that, sets true length. Check for `SET_TRUELENGTH` in R_internals.h (or envir.c). It was designed to be used for over-allocation in R at some point but never got to be used as intended (IIRC from reading a post on r-devel some months ago). Here, we set it to 0 explicitly before `alloc.col` call because R versions > 2.14 doesn't set this by default (from data.table comments under settruelength C function). Why we need it, I'm not sure.. because, in `alloc.col`, we do set the actual true length anyways.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077761/strange-difference-between-x-and-getx) from Matthew will help shed more light on `truelength`.

Comment: Thanks Arun. @MattDowle could you explain the point of the `settruelength` command here?

Comment: @eddi Before R2.14.0, the `truelength` member of R's vector header wasn't initialized by R. In C if you don't initialize a variable it has undefined contents (whatever happens to be in that chunk of RAM previously). `data.table()` and similar creators initialize `truelength` to 0 before calling `alloc.col` for compatibility with pre R 2.14.0. `alloc.col` looks at `truelength` as an input (0 is taken to mean truelength==length). At one point I thought data.table would need to depend on R>=2.14.0 because of this, but managed to keep it R>=2.12.0. I test with R2.12.0 before each release to CRAN.

Comment: You probably want to explicitly add that `as.data.table` returns a copy.