# Convert a data.table to a data frame without copying

Tags: r, data.table

[This question and answer set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy) asks how to convert a data.frame to a data.table without copying and shows how to do so using a manual method and the excellent `setDT()` function.

How would one safely convert back *from* a data.table *to* a data frame without copying? The issues and reasoning are similar to the question linked above.

Comment: I think there's a `setDF` function coming your way.

Comment: On my phone right now, so not easy to really hunt around, but i found this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/338

Comment: As Ananda points out, this has been implemented in 1.9.3. But I don't understand the reasoning. Could you elaborate on why you'd want to go back to a data.frame?

Comment: @Arun some people don't like `data.table` syntax but do like `fread` speed

Comment: If they've data large enough to benefit from `fread`, I'd imagine they've a lot more to benefit from `data.table`'s speed *and* syntax. I'd just encourage people to [read the >100 independent reviews on crantastic](http://crantastic.org/packages/data-table) and try it out themselves, before deciding based on off-handed comments.

Comment: `data.table`-objects inherit the `data.frame`-class. If you type `class(DT)` with such an object, you should get `[1] "data.table", "data.frame"`,  so there is really no need to do this.

Comment: @BondedDust, true. And it even detects if a package is data.table aware. But some people are too picky about the fact that they've to use `with=FALSE` for example when selecting columns the data.frame way: `DT[, c("a", "b"), with=FALSE]`.. Can't think of other reasons really..

Comment: I suspect that using `class(DT) <- "data.frame"` would create a copy, since I seem to remember from discussion on r-devel that assignment to attributes does make copies. I wonder if the annoying behavior of `[.data.table` could just be fixed by overwriting that function.

Comment: You're right about the copy (R v < 3.1 creates deep copies, whereas 3.1+ creates shallow copy). The idiomatic way would be to use `setattr(DT, 'class', 'data.frame')`. This and removal of some attributes is what `setDF` in 1.9.3 does (implemented due to user request on data.table mailing list).

Comment: @Arun, in this case, I'm converting back to a data.frame so that I can write an "RData" image to share as part of a public dataset. I don't want there to be a dependency on the data.table package. In the past, reading data.table back into memory from a saved image but I believe these issues have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an entirely misguided idea for all the reasons listed in the comments above, and probably ones that I am not aware of, but you can replace the `[.data.table` function with `[data.frame`. That would prevent the problem raised by @Arun regarding needing to use an extra argument for the `[`-function:

```
 assignInNamespace( "[.data.table", getAnywhere( `[.data.frame`), ns="data.table")
```

All of the functions which would normally check for 'data.frame'-class would already have worked normally because of inheritance.

Edit: The comment by Arun provides a much less drastic approach, since over-writing the core data.table '['-function is essentially "dishonest". I suppose a more honest approach would be to unLoad the entire NAMESPACE. If the goal is to just use `fread`, I wonder if there could just be importation of that functions and any dependencies.

```
 setattr(DT, 'class', 'data.frame')
```

But still see this as a "step backward."

Comment: Why is this a step backwards? Just because it's not using data.table? You can see my comment for why I am doing this above.

Comment: OK, maybe it's not a bad idea in a specific context where you don't intend to do anything further. Does `setattr` solve the problem for you?

Comment: In more recent versions, [setDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36671588/1048186) is the way to go.