# Convert data.table to data.frame (i.e. undo setDT)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a 20x2 dataframe. I converted that dataframe to a data.table to perform some operations (deleted the explanation of the operations and goal as out of scope). The conversion allowed me to avoid using a for loop. But the conversion generates some issues down the line.

I need to convert the df data.table back into a data.frame. How can I do that?

Thanks very much for your help.

```
df <- data.frame(LastPrice = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205), KCT = c( 1218, 1218, 1219, 1218, 1221,  1217 , 1217, 1216, 1219, 1216, 1217, 1216, 1219, 1217, 1218, 1217, 1217, 1217, 1219, 1217))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, check := as.integer(LastPrice > KCT)]
df[, Signal := do.call(pmin, shift(check, 0:2, type="lead"))]
```

Comment: Just like `setDT()`, there is `setDF()`

Comment: EUREKA. Spent half a day debugging this thing to finally discover the data.table format was a my problem. This fixed it. Thank you. Do you want to put this as a response so I may mark the question as answered? Or maybe the question is just too basic, and should be deleted...

Comment: @Hadd This one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/25020092/ It doesn't have a setDF answer (yet), though

Comment: No question is too basic so that it should be deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a data.table to a data frame without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020092/convert-a-data-table-to-a-data-frame-without-copying)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like `setDT()` converts its input to a data table by reference, there is also `setDF()` which converts its input to a data frame by reference.  So just call

```
setDF(df)
```

and you are back to a data frame with no copies made.