# Efficient Way to Incrementally Count Unique Data Points in Data Frame

Tags: r, count, dataframe

I am trying to find a more efficient way to incrementally count unique data points in a data frame.

For example, I have the following code written:

```
df = matrix(c(1,2,3,3,4,5,1,2,4,4))

count = matrix(nrow = nrow(df),ncol=1)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  count[i,1] = length(which(df[1:i,1] == df[i,1]))

}
```

The purpose of the code is to incrementally count each instance of a specific value, e.g. the **count** column will have the following result:

```
1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3.
```

The code I have written so far does the job, however the sample df above only contains 10 values. The real data frame I am trying to perform this function on contains `52,118 values`, which takes an enormous amount of time.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way to execute the code above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(20)
dat  <-data.frame(values = sample(1:3, 50000, replace=TRUE))
setDT(dat)[,runningCount:=1:.N,values]

       values runningCount
    1:      3            1
    2:      3            2
    3:      1            1
    4:      2            1
    5:      3            3
   ---                    
49996:      1        16674
49997:      2        16516
49998:      2        16517
49999:      2        16518
50000:      2        16519
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback everyone! I am trying to implement the "data.table" and "dplyr" methods since they make the most sense to me. That being said, I keep getting an error saying "setDT" function not found when using the "data.table" method. Why is that?

Comment: which version of data.table are you using? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy. Also, argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'

Comment: My dataset is a data.frame, so that's fine. The version of data.table I have is 1.9.4. I just downloaded it like 20 minutes ago.

Comment: What is the exact error? Does `data.table::setDT(dat)[,runningCount:=1:.N,values]` help? (No to load data.table package in this case)

Comment: I just fixed it. I was only running a portion of the code, so it wasn't able to reference to the other data set. Thanks so much for you help! If you don't mind, can you explain what "setDT" does? and also, is "runningCount" a function within the data.table package? I was looking for a solution forever and never came across runningcount.

Comment: `runningCount` is just the name we gave to the new column. `setDT()` is a `data.table` function for modifying a data frame.

Comment: What both the `dplyr` and `data.table` answers do, essentially, is (1) split the data into three separate groups--one for each of the three possible values of `values`, (2) perform an operation separately on each group, in this case the addition of a column with a running counter of the number of rows in that group (this is done using `1:.N` in `data.table` and `1:n()` in `dplyr`; in both cases, this is equivalent to `1:length(x)` where `x` is any vector). (3) combine the three separate groups back together into a single data frame in its original order.

Comment: That is a great explanation! I assume that in the scenario you're talking about, there would only be three groups because there are three unique values. If there were 1,000+ unique values, then there would be 1,000+ groups, right? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, only 3 groups here, but the same applies to any number of groups. This is the "split-apply-combine` strategy. See [this article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) by Hadley Wickham (creator of `dplyr`) for a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fast approach with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(20)
dat  = data.frame(values = sample(1:3, 50000, replace=TRUE))

dat %>% group_by(values) %>%
  mutate(runningCount = 1:n())

   values runningCount
1       2            1
2       3            1
3       1            1
4       3            2
5       1            2
6       3            3
7       3            4
..    ...          ...
```

Timing (in milliseconds):

```
     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max  neval
2.003755 2.134762 2.198161 2.186214 2.231662 3.665328    100
```

Timings for all answers so far (using the data I created):

```
                median
        dplyr:   2.11
   data.table:   1.24
lapply/Reduce:  11.61
          ave:   9.93
```

So `data.table` is the fastest.

Answer (score 6):

One base `R` approach:

```
Reduce(`+`,lapply(unique(c(df)), function(u){b=c(df)==u;b[b==T]=cumsum(b[b==T]);b}))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 3
```