# When should I use setDT() instead of data.table() to create a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am having difficulty grasping the essence of the `setDT()` function. As I read code on SO, I frequently come across the use of `setDT()` to create a data.table. Of course the use of `data.table()` is ubiquitous. I feel like I solidly comprehend the nature of `data.table()` yet the relevance of `setDT()` eludes me. `?setDT` tells me this:

> `setDT` converts lists (both named and unnamed) and data.frames to data.tables *by reference*.

as well as:

> In `data.table` parlance, all `set*` functions change their input by reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory, which is as large as one column.

So this makes me think I should only use `setDT()` to make a data.table, right? Is `setDT()` simply a list to data.table converter?

```
library(data.table)

a <- letters[c(19,20,1,3,11,15,22,5,18,6,12,15,23)]
b <- seq(1,41,pi)
ab <- data.frame(a,b)
d <- data.table(ab)
e <- setDT(ab)

str(d)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 13 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 12 levels "a","c","e","f",..: 9 10 1 2 5 7 11 3 8 4 ...
# $ b: num  1 4.14 7.28 10.42 13.57 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

str(e)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 13 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 12 levels "a","c","e","f",..: 9 10 1 2 5 7 11 3 8 4 ...
# $ b: num  1 4.14 7.28 10.42 13.57 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Seemingly no difference in this instance. In another instance the difference is evident:

```
ba <- list(a,b)
f <- data.table(ba)
g <- setDT(ba)

str(f)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ ba:List of 2
#  ..$ : chr  "s" "t" "a" "c" ...
#  ..$ : num  1 4.14 7.28 10.42 13.57 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

str(g)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 13 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "s" "t" "a" "c" ...
# $ V2: num  1 4.14 7.28 10.42 13.57 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

When should I use `setDT()`? What makes `setDT()` relevant? Why not just make the original `data.table()` function capable of doing what `setDT()` is able to do?

Comment: If the data already exists in a data.frame and you're happy to convert that data.frame (or list) to data.table in place, then use setDT(). If you want to construct a data.table from vectors or something, use data.table(). You should never be doing `x <- setDT(y)` -- I think you are misunderstanding what it means for the object to be modified by reference. Might want to have a run through the vignettes: http://r-datatable.com/Getting-Started

Comment: And, see what happens to the `ab` data.table after assigning new columns to `d` and `e`: `d[, newCol := 1]; ab; e[, newCol := 1]; ab`.

Comment: @Frank I will jump back in the literature. As you may know, it takes many iterations for things to click for some folks-- like myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Whoa! That's crazy... they have become connected. `ab` updates with changes to `e` from the use of `setDT()`. Weird! Now I get to spend the next few days trying to wrap my head around that.

Comment: That's why it's important to understand what "update-by-reference" (i.e., `setDT()`) does, when compared to taking a copy (i.e. `data.table()`) of an object.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

***Update:***

> **@Roland** makes some good points in the comments section, and the post is better for them. While I originally focused on memory overflow issues, he pointed out that even if this doesn't happen, memory management of various copies takes substantial time, which is a more common everyday concern. Examples of both issues have now been added as well.

I like this question on stackoverflow because I think it is really about avoiding stack overflow in R when dealing with larger data sets.   Those who are unfamiliar with `data.table` family of `set` operations may benefit from this discussion!

One should use `setDT()` when working with larger data sets that take up a considerable amount of RAM because the operation will modify each object in place, conserving memory. For data that is a very small percentage of RAM, using data.table’s copy-and-modify is fine.

The creation of the `setDT` function was actually inspired by the following thread on stack overflow, which is about working with a large data set (several GB's). You will see Matt Dowle chime in an suggest the 'setDT' name.

[Convert a data frame to a data.table without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy)

**A bit more depth:**

With R, data is stored in memory. This speeds things up considerably because RAM is much faster to access than storage devices. However, a problem can arise when one’s data set is a large portion of RAM. Why? Because base R has a tendency to make copies of each `data.frame` when some operations are applied to them. This has improved after version 3.1, but addressing that is beyond the scope of this post. If one is pulling multiple `data.frame`s or `list`s into one `data.frame` or `data.table`, your memory usage will expand rather quickly because at some point during the operation, multiple copies of your data exist in RAM. If the data set is big enough, you may run out of memory when all the copies are produced, and your stack will overflow. See example of this below. We get an error, and original memory address and class of object does not change.

```
> N <- 1e8
> P <- 1e2
> data <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), P))
> 
> pryr::object_size(data)
800 MB
> 
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<0000000006D2DF18>"
> 
> data <- data.table(data)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 762.9 Mb
> 
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<0000000006D2DF18>"
> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
>
```

The ability to just modify the object in place without copying is a big deal. That is what `setDT` does when it takes a `list` or `data.frame` and returns a `data.table`. The same example as above using `setDT`, now works fine and without error. Both class and memory address change, and no copies take place.

```
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<0000000006D2DF18>"
> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
> 
> setDT(data)
>  
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<0000000006A8C758>"
> class(data)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

@Roland points out that for most people, the bigger concern is speed, which suffers as a side effect of such intensive use of memory management. Here is an example with smaller data that does not crash the cpu, and illustrates how much faster `setDT` is for this job. Notice the results of 'tracemem' in the wake of `data <- data.table(data)`, making copies of `data`. Contrast that with `setDT(data)` which doesn't print a single copy. We have to then call `tracemem(data)` to see the new memory address.

```
> N <- 1e5
> P <- 1e2
> data <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), P))
> pryr::object_size(data)
808 kB

> # data.table method
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<0000000019098438>"
> data <- data.table(data)
tracemem[0x0000000019098438 -> 0x0000000007aad7d8]: data.table 
tracemem[0x0000000007aad7d8 -> 0x0000000007c518b8]: copy as.data.table.data.frame as.data.table data.table 
tracemem[0x0000000007aad7d8 -> 0x0000000018e454c8]: as.list.data.frame as.list vapply copy as.data.table.data.frame as.data.table data.table 
> class(data)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> 
> # setDT method
> # back to data.frame
> data <- as.data.frame(data)
> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<00000000125BE1A0>"
> setDT(data)
> tracemem(data)
[1] "<00000000125C2840>"
> class(data)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
>
```

How does this impact timing? As we can see, `setDT` is much faster for it.

```
> # timing example
> data <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), P))
> microbenchmark(setDT(data), data <- data.table(data))
Unit: microseconds
                     expr       min         lq        mean    median            max neval        uq
              setDT(data)    49.948    55.7635    69.66017    73.553        100.238   100    79.198
 data <- data.table(data) 54594.289 61238.8830 81545.64432 64179.131     611632.427   100 68647.917
```

Set functions can be used in many areas, not just when converting objects to a data.tables. You can find more information on the reference semantics and how to apply them elsewhere by calling the vignette on the subject.

```
library(data.table)    
vignette("datatable-reference-semantics")
```

This is a great question and those thinking of using R with larger data sets or who just want to speed up data manipulation actives, can benefit from being familiar with the significant performance improvements of `data.table` reference semantics.

Comment: You focus too much on memory. Changes by reference vs by copy have also huge speed implications which is more relevant for most people. A good answer should contain some benchmarks. Also, you shouldn't rely too much on information from ancient posts regarding these issues. Base R's memory management has evolved since 2009.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the comments, and I always try to take a humble approach on these matters. However, upon looking deeper at this, I must say that my answer is in line with what the authors of data.table write in their documentation. Specifically, they created `setDT` to convert data.frames to data.tables ***without copy***. Please see `?setDT`. In fact, they even point to the same stack overflow post I listed above. Thanks

Comment: I think you are missing my point. Copies don't only need additional memory but the memory management takes substantial time. That's why avoiding copies is not only memory efficient but also time efficient.

Comment: Ok, yes I see your point now! I updated the post above, which I think is much better for your comments. Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 23):

`setDT()` is not a replacement for `data.table()`. It's a more efficient replacement for `as.data.table()` which can be used with certain types of objects.

- `mydata <- as.data.table(mydata)` will copy the object behind `mydata`, convert the copy to a `data.table`, then change the `mydata` symbol to point to the copy.
- `setDT(mydata)` will change the object behind `mydata` to a `data.table`. No copying is done.

So what's a realistic situation to use `setDT()`?  When you can't control the class of the original data. For instance, most packages for working with databases give `data.frame` output. In that case, your code would be something like

```
mydata <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM mytable")  # Returns a data.frame
setDT(mydata)                                        # Make it a data.table
```

When should you use `as.data.table(x)`? Whenever `x` isn't a `list` or `data.frame`. The most common use is for matrices.

Comment: Small nitpick: In your first bullet point you refer to a variable when you mean the mydata [symbol](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Symbol-objects).

Comment: The last question is not going to be answered as is. Better to make a separate example. my 2 cents