# Tidyverse approach to binding unnamed list of unnamed vectors by row - do.call(rbind,x) equivalent

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

I often find questions where people have somehow ended up with an *unnamed* list of *unnamed* character vectors and they want to bind them row-wise into a `data.frame`. Here is an example:

```
library(magrittr)
data <- cbind(LETTERS[1:3],1:3,4:6,7:9,c(12,15,18)) %>%
  split(1:3) %>% unname
data
#[[1]]
#[1] "A"  "1"  "4"  "7"  "12"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "B"  "2"  "5"  "8"  "15"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "C"  "3"  "6"  "9"  "18"
```

One typical approach is with `do.call` from base R.

```
do.call(rbind, data) %>% as.data.frame
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  A  1  4  7 12
#2  B  2  5  8 15
#3  C  3  6  9 18
```

Perhaps a less efficient approach is with `Reduce` from base R.

```
Reduce(rbind,data, init = NULL) %>% as.data.frame
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  A  1  4  7 12
#2  B  2  5  8 15
#3  C  3  6  9 18
```

However, when we consider more modern packages such as `dplyr` or `data.table`, some of the approaches that might immediately come to mind don't work because the vectors are unnamed or aren't a list.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(data)
#Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(data)
#Error in rbindlist(data) : 
#  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

One approach might be to `set_names` on the vectors.

```
library(purrr)
map_df(data, ~set_names(.x, seq_along(.x)))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`  
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A     1     4     7     12   
#2 B     2     5     8     15   
#3 C     3     6     9     18
```

However, this seems like more steps than it needs to be.

Therefore, my question is what is an efficient `tidyverse` or `data.table` approach to binding an *unnamed* list of *unnamed* character vectors into a `data.frame` row-wise?

Comment: As a side note, `Reduce(rbind, ` cannot be more efficient than `do.call(rbind, ` since the `do.call` construct allocates memory and copies data once, while the `Reduce` construct repeatedly allocates new memory and re-copies all previously "`rbind`ed" elements.

Comment: You're quite correct. I didn't expect the performance hit as bad as it is, 6,000 times slower on 100,000 rows.  I edited the question to call this a "less efficient approach".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not entirely sure about efficiency, but a compact option using `purrr` and `tibble` could be:

```
map_dfc(purrr::transpose(data), ~ unlist(tibble(.)))

  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     1     4     7     12   
2 B     2     5     8     15   
3 C     3     6     9     18
```

Comment: @Adam updated the post, thank you :) I cannot recall a `tidyverse` function that is faster or as fast as a `data.table` function for the same thing, though.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit**

Use [@sindri_baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4552295/sindri-baldur)'s approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61660119/8583393

---

A way with `data.table`, similar to what @tmfmnk showed

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(transpose(data))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1:  A  1  4  7 12
#2:  B  2  5  8 15
#3:  C  3  6  9 18
```

Answer (score 10):

```
library(data.table)
setDF(transpose(data))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  A  1  4  7 12
2  B  2  5  8 15
3  C  3  6  9 18
```

Comment: I just ran a benchmark with some other methods. This crushes everything else in terms of speed and is the first one to actually beat the `base::rbind()` solution.

Comment: @dww Yes, but  `setDF()` is different from `as.data.table()` / `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: @Adam, Do you think you could update your benchmark with the newer solution? For those unaware of how `setDF()`/`setDT()` work then here is good post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44938350/4552295

Answer (score 9):

This seems rather compact. I believe this is what powers `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` and therefore `map_df()` in `purrr`, so should be fairly efficient.

```r
library(vctrs)

vec_rbind(!!!data)
```

This gives a data.frame.

```r
  ...1 ...2 ...3 ...4 ...5
1    A    1    4    7   12
2    B    2    5    8   15
3    C    3    6    9   18
```

---

### Some Benchmarks

It seems like the `.name_repair` within the `tidyverse` methods is a severe bottleneck. I took a few fairly straightforward options that also seemed to run the quickest from the other posts (thanks H 1 and sindri_baldur).

```r
microbenchmark(vctrs = vec_rbind(!!!data),
               dt = rbindlist(lapply(data, as.list)),
               map = map_df(data, as_tibble_row, .name_repair = "unique"),
               base = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, data)))
```

[image: benchmark 1]

But if you first name the vectors (but not necessarily the list elements), you get a different story.

```r
data2 <- modify(data, ~set_names(.x, seq(.x)))

microbenchmark(vctrs = vec_rbind(!!!data2),
               dt = rbindlist(lapply(data2, as.list)),
               map = map_df(data2, as_tibble_row),
               base = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, data2)))
```

[image: benchmark 2]

In fact, you can include the time to name the vectors into the `vec_rbind()` solution and not the others, and still see fairly high performance.

```r
microbenchmark(vctrs = vec_rbind(!!!modify(data, ~set_names(.x, seq(.x)))),
               dt = setDF(transpose(data)),
               map = map_df(data2, as_tibble_row),
               base = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, data)))
```

[image: final benchmark]

For what its worth.

Comment: You might further improve performance by setting the names to just an integer that doesn't require `paste`.

Comment: Maybe something like `vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!lapply(data,function(x){attr(x,"names") <- 1:5; x}))`. But for answering everyday questions that people can understand, this is less than ideal.

Comment: Yeah, that gets a bit quicker than what I just did. But I agree. I am tempted to open a feature request in `vctrs` to see if they can resolve the names ahead of time. I am out of play time for this. But this is an interesting problem. Feel free to edit this post with benchmarks, take them and move them into another post, or anything you like. But I think the setDF() option will be your winner.

Answer (score 6):

My approach would be to just turn those list entries into expected type

```r
rbindlist(lapply(data, as.list))
#       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
#   <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>
#1:      A      1      4      7     12
#2:      B      2      5      8     15
#3:      C      3      6      9     18
```

---

If you want your data types to be adjusted from character vector to appropriate types, then `lapply` can help here as well. First `lapply` is called for every row, second `lapply` is called for every column.

```r
rbindlist(lapply(data, as.list))[, lapply(.SD, type.convert)]
       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
   <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1:      A     1     4     7    12
2:      B     2     5     8    15
3:      C     3     6     9    18
```

Answer (score 5):

An option with `unnest_wider`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(col = data) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(col), names_repair = ~ str_c('value', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 A      1      4      7      12    
#2 B      2      5      8      15    
#3 C      3      6      9      18
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slight variation on tmfmnk's suggested approach using `as_tibble_row()` to convert the vectors into single row tibbles.  It's also necessary to use the `.name_repair` argument:

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

map_df(data, as_tibble_row, .name_repair = ~paste0("value", seq(.x)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 A      1      4      7      12    
2 B      2      5      8      15    
3 C      3      6      9      18
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be added to an already complete set of very good answers to this question:

```
library(rlang) # Or purrr

data %>%
  exec(rbind, !!!.) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  set_names(~ letters[seq_along(.)])

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  a     b     c     d     e    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     1     4     7     12   
2 B     2     5     8     15   
3 C     3     6     9     18
```