# Loading a data frame into R and using setDT

Tags: r, data.table

I am loading a large dataset into R (roughly 40GBs), and I was wondering if I can wrap setDT() around the data while loading it in. For example, I was wondering if there is a difference between using (A) or (B), and if one or another is more efficient. Thanks in advance!

```
(A) dt = setDT(dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM data")) 

(B) dt = dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM data)
    setDT(dt)
```

Comment: `fread` function may be also a candidate. Why don't you test them on a small data set firstly.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I will try that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917887/when-should-i-use-setdt-instead-of-data-table-to-create-a-data-table ; setDT transforms in place to a data.table. So I would say A and B are the same.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you.

Comment: Confirming there is no difference between (A) & (B); all `setDT()` does is add the `data.table` class to the object, and allocate column pointers.