# Optimize R data.table code of a function inside an R package

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to optimize a function that lives inside an R package that leverages on `{data.table}` code.

### Motivation for question

I do not use `{data.table}` very often, although I do spend a significant amount of time reading the documentation when I am at it. Yet, I always struggle with `{data.table}`'s syntax, particularly when I have to deal with NSE. I did read [Programming on data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html)
, and other vignettes.

I am confident that for an experienced `{data.table}` user the code that follows next can be straightforwardly optimized, made more terse, and readable, by making a better use of idiomatic `{data.table}` code. But I do not know how. Hence my question. I will be specific about the places in the code where I think there might be another way of writing it (I hope you don't judge this as an open-ended question about optimization).

### Conceptual problem

I have this function `find_overlap()` (full code down below) that takes a data frame `df` (millions of rows), two numerical intervals/ranges (`time_range` and `speed_range`), and a set of column names to be operated on (`time_col`, `speed_col`, `lon_col`, `lat_col`). All these columns indicated by these names are of type numeric.

Essentially, for each observation `i` of the data frame `df`, i.e.., a point in space and time, I would like to iterate over a subset of other points also in `df` and find the closest point to `i`. The subset is defined by two conditions:

- Points (observations) must fall in a time range (`time_range`, a two-element vector with lower and upper bounds). This is a relative time range, not an absolute one. The actual absolute range is calculated by adding the time of observation `i` --- saved in variables `t_lower` and `t_upper`.
- Points (observations) must fall in a speed range.

At the end I want to return the data frame (a data table really) updated, i.e., including two extra columns:

- `arg_min_dist`: an index of the found closest observation/point, or `NA` if none found
- `min_dist`: the distance

### `{data.table}` optimization questions

1. At the beginning of the function, I create an index column in `dt[['..id..']] <- seq.int(nrow(dt))`. The objective is to have a way of keeping track of the identity of the observation corresponding to the closest point, so that I can return it in `arg_min_dist`. This feels not ideal, I suspect there might be a way of extracting a row id without having to explicitly create the row index myself, i.e. along the lines of `dplyr::row_number()`.
2. The column whose name is in `time_col` will correspond to a column with timings, namely a simple numeric variable (it is not a date or time object), and the data frame will be sorted by this column. I am adding a key based on this column in `data.table::setkeyv(dt, c(time_col))`. Is this advantageous or by being already sorted the data table at this point am I incurring in an expensive operation with no added benefit?
3. Next, I am having an explicit for loop, where for each observation `i`, I subset the data table and find the closest point. I am guessing there might be a way of instructing `{data.table}` to do it instead, which will be faster and akin to `{data.table}`'s parallelization based on threads.
4. The sub-setting itself in:

```
      dt_subset <-
        dt[dt[[time_col]] >= t_lower[i] &
             dt[[time_col]] < t_upper[i] &
             dt[[speed_col]] >= speed_range[1] &
             dt[[speed_col]] < speed_range[2], c('..id..', lon_col, lat_col), with = FALSE]
```

raises a few questions.

Are `dt[[time_col]]` and `dt[[speed_col]]` generating a copy of each of those columns, and not working by reference? Also, I wonder if swapping `>=` and `<` with `{data table}`'s `%between%` would be faster.

5. Then the part where I actually calculate the distance between points with the function `spDistsN1()`, and find the minimum distance, probably all that could be fit into a single function that would return only the two columns of interest `arg_min_dist` and `min_dist`. I know that `{data.table}`'s `j` argument accepts expressions, not only column selection.

```
      if (nrow(dt_subset) > 0) {
        distances <- spDistsN1(pt_x = dt[[lon_col]][i],
                               pt_y = dt[[lat_col]][i],
                               pts_x = dt_subset[[lon_col]],
                               pts_y = dt_subset[[lat_col]],
                               longlat = TRUE)

        iii <- which.min(distances)
        if (length(iii) > 0) {
          arg_min_dist[i] <- dt_subset[iii, '..id..']
          min_dist[i] <- distances[iii]
        }
      }
```

Having such `j` expression would also save me from performing that `cbind()` at the end.

### Note about MWE

I am not including a MWE because the function `spDistsN1()` is compiled. If you find it really necessary I can adapt the code at that point so that it runs, but I believe my questions are well illustrated with the code as is.

### `find_overlap()`

```
find_overlap <-
  function(df,
           time_range,
           speed_range,
           time_col = 'DATE',
           speed_col = 'SPE',
           lon_col = 'LON',
           lat_col = 'LAT') {

    n_row <- nrow(df)
    # dt <- setup_dt(df, time_col = time_col)
    dt <- data.table::as.data.table(df)
    dt[['..id..']] <- seq.int(nrow(dt))
    data.table::setkeyv(dt, c(time_col))

    t_lower <- as.data.frame(dt[ , time_col, with = FALSE])[, 1] + time_range[1]
    t_upper <- as.data.frame(dt[ , time_col, with = FALSE])[, 1] + time_range[2]

    arg_min_dist <- rep(NA_integer_, length = n_row)
    min_dist <- rep(NA_real_, length = n_row)

    for (i in seq_len(n_row)) {

      dt_subset <-
        dt[dt[[time_col]] >= t_lower[i] &
             dt[[time_col]] < t_upper[i] &
             dt[[speed_col]] >= speed_range[1] &
             dt[[speed_col]] < speed_range[2], c('..id..', lon_col, lat_col), with = FALSE]

      if (nrow(dt_subset) > 0) {
        distances <- spDistsN1(pt_x = dt[[lon_col]][i],
                               pt_y = dt[[lat_col]][i],
                               pts_x = dt_subset[[lon_col]],
                               pts_y = dt_subset[[lat_col]],
                               longlat = TRUE)

        iii <- which.min(distances)
        if (length(iii) > 0) {
          arg_min_dist[i] <- dt_subset[iii, '..id..']
          min_dist[i] <- distances[iii]
        }
      }
    }

    return(cbind(dt, arg_min_dist, min_dist))

  }
```

Comment: For (1), you can use `dt[,id:=.I]` to create an id column. For what is probably  your main question (i.e.  issues (3)/(4)), I might start by considering using a non-equi join of `dt` on itself, with conditions generated by speed and time ranges. Can you provide 10-20 rows of the initial table, and an example time and speed range?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

1. I define a data.table as below, which may or may not be close to the structure that you have

```
dt=data.table(
  DATE=sample(seq(as.IDate('2020-01-01'), as.IDate("2022-12-31"), length.out=10000), 1000),
  SPE = sample(seq(1,50, length.out=10000), 1000),
  LAT = sample(seq(-100,100, length.out=10000), 1000),
  LON = sample(seq(-100,100, length.out=10000), 1000)
)
```

2. I define a function that is similar to yours, but tries to address your questions re (2)(3)(4), above. Note that for illustrative purposes, I'm treating the LAT, LON values like simple points in the coordinate plane (see my simple distance calculation)

```
find_overlap <-function(
  df, time_range,speed_range,time_col = DATE,speed_col = SPE,x = LAT,y = LON) {
  
  ixcol = paste0("i.", substitute(x))
  iycol = paste0("i.", substitute(y))
  
  # create the id and the lower and upper bounds
  eval(substitute(
    df[,`:=`(
      id=.I,
      tlower=time_col+time_range[1],tupper=time_col+time_range[2],
      slower=speed_col+speed_range[1],supper=speed_col+speed_range[2])]
  ))
  
  
  # merge df on itself, using no-equi join and rename cols as needed
  sdf =eval(substitute(
    df[df, on=.(
      time_col>=tlower,time_col<=tupper,
      speed_col>=slower,speed_col<=supper
    )][, .(time_col, speed_col, x, y, id,close_id = i.id,close_x = get(ixcol),close_y = get(iycol))]
  ))
  
  # get the distance
  eval(substitute(
    sdf[,distance:=sqrt((x-close_x)^2  + (y-close_y)^2)]
  ))
  
  
  # get the datatable with the closest id
  sdf <- sdf[order(id,distance)][id!=close_id][,.SD[1], by=id][,.(id,closest = close_id, distance)]
  
  # merge back on original
  sdf[df[,.(id)], on=.(id)]
}
```

Example usage - here, `time_range` and `speed_range` are given in relative terms. I.e. we are restricting points that are within +- 3 days and +- 4 speed units

```
find_overlap(dt, c(-3,3), c(-4,4))
```

Output:

```
        id closest   distance
   1:    1      NA         NA
   2:    2     437  20.212474
   3:    3     911   6.023127
   4:    4     307  36.567841
   5:    5     438 181.974809
  ---                        
 996:  996     483 162.941772
 997:  997     956 154.148418
 998:  998     707  78.425606
 999:  999      14  76.611228
1000: 1000     725  91.395353
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am analyzing it now.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Error in `:=`(id = .I, tlower = DATE + time_range[1], tupper = DATE + : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")`. I added `#' @importFrom data.table ":="` to the function roxygen2 block, but it does not solve this specific issue. Would you know how I make this work from within a package?

Comment: sorry for asking the obvious, but are you passing to `df` an object that is a data.table?.. In general, I normally just include `#' @import data.table` in packages that i write that require the use of data.table.  you could also add `setDT(df)` as the first line of your function, to ensure that the object passed to `df` becomes a data.table (if it isn't already)

Comment: Solved. I've used `usethis::use_data_table()` and all the necessary setup has been done. I also added the line `df <- data.table::as.data.table(df)` to the beginning of your function. I am trying to adapt your function now to use my distance compiled function instead. Just saw your comment, is `setDT(df)` more efficient than `data.table::as.data.table(df)`?

Comment: great!.  i do think you should replace that `as.data.table` call with `setDT` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917887/when-should-i-use-setdt-instead-of-data-table-to-create-a-data-tableable

Comment: Also you've left the setting of a key out of your function. Is that because in this case it provides no benefit? Or should I do `setDT(df, key = c(time_col, speed_col))`?

Comment: hmm, there might be instances where it helps, I'm really not sure.  When I tested with a relatively small table of 10,000 rows, I could not see a difference when I set the key vs  not setting it (i.e. median 104 milliseconds vs  median109 milliseconds, over 100 iterations, with and without keying, respectively).

Comment: I see that the column names are as of now hard-coded as bare names, not taking advantage of `time_col`, `speed_col`, `lon_col`, `lat_col`. This is precisely one of the points where I struggle with data.table when integrating code into an R package. Would you be able to indicate how to adapt the code to work with the column names passed as argument variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241938/discussion-between-langtang-and-plant).

Comment: I've edited the response, to avoid hard coding variables