# Dropping a column from a data.table corrupts a derived table

Tags: r, data.table

I create a data.table (`DT2`) to describe the columns of another data.table (`DT1`).
I do the same using a slightly different syntax (`DT3`).
`DT2` and `DT3` are identical.
I then drop a column from the source table (`DT1`)
The `DT2` table is now corrupt, but `DT3` is unchanged.

---

### Example code

```r
require(data.table)
#> Loading required package: data.table
#Make a data.table with 4 columns and 3 rows
DT1 <- data.table(col1 = c('A','B','C'), 
                  col2 = c(1,2,3), 
                  col3 = c(NA, NA, NA), 
                  col4 = c('Jane', 'Harry', 'Arlo'))
#Describe the columns of the above table using 2 alternative syntax
DT2 <- setDT(data.frame(column = colnames(DT1), 
                        class = sapply(DT1, function(x) class(x)[1])))
DT3 <- data.table(column = colnames(DT1), 
                        class = sapply(DT1, function(x) class(x)[1]))
#The results are the same
identical(DT2, DT3)
#> [1] TRUE

#Drop a column from the original table
DT1[, col3 := NULL]
#Now three columns and three rows
DT1[]
#>    col1 col2  col4
#> 1:    A    1  Jane
#> 2:    B    2 Harry
#> 3:    C    3  Arlo

#But the DT2 description is now corrupt!
DT2[]
#> Warning in cbind(column = c("col1", "col2", "col4"), class = c("character", :
#> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
#> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn: length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
#DT3 is OK
DT3[]
#>    column     class
#> 1:   col1 character
#> 2:   col2   numeric
#> 3:   col3   logical
#> 4:   col4 character
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

There appears to be some internal cross-reference between the `DT2` and the source `DT1` tables that is not obvious. Can anyone provide an explanation of what is going on here?
`setDT(data.frame())` appears to have the same outcome as `data.table()`, but not actually so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use setDT() instead of data.table() to create a data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917887/when-should-i-use-setdt-instead-of-data-table-to-create-a-data-table)

Comment: `setDT` will "change their input by *reference*."

Comment: @AndrewGB Thanks for the link.  This does point towards an explanation, but still very strange that it results in corruption of the table.  Some columns of DT2 have 4 rows and some have 3 after removing a column from another table.  It appears that one column of DT2 (the setDT table) is just a reference to a `colnames` list of DT1, but the other columns are new. So when the column is removed from DT1, only one column in DT2 loses an entry. Tricky!