# Column manipulation in R - data stored as column name

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I have a data frame of strangely formatted data, where information is stored as part of the column name.

```
library(tidyverse)

Ihave <- frame_data(
  ~ID,~group,~AAA_info2_BBB,~CCC_info3_DDD,
  "first",  1, as.Date("1970-01-01"), as.Date("1970-01-02"),
  "second", 2, as.Date("1971-01-01"), as.Date("1971-01-02"),
  "third",  3, as.Date("1972-01-01"), as.Date("1972-01-02"),
)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID     group AAA_info2_BBB CCC_info3_DDD
  <chr>  <dbl> <date>        <date>       
1 first      1 1970-01-01    1970-01-02   
2 second     2 1971-01-01    1971-01-02   
3 third      3 1972-01-01    1972-01-02
```

I would need to get the information back in the data frame, as shown below

```
Iwant <-  frame_data(
  ~ID,~group,~source,~variable,~value,~period,
  "first",  1, "AAA", "info1", as.Date("1970-01-01"), "BBB",
  "second", 2, "AAA", "info1", as.Date("1971-01-01"), "BBB",
  "third",  3, "AAA", "info1", as.Date("1972-01-01"), "BBB",
  "first",  1, "CCC", "info2", as.Date("1970-01-02"), "DDD",
  "second", 2, "CCC", "info2", as.Date("1971-01-02"), "DDD",
  "third",  3, "CCC", "info2", as.Date("1972-01-02"), "DDD",
)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ID     group source variable value      period
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <date>     <chr> 
1 first      1 AAA    info1    1970-01-01 BBB   
2 second     2 AAA    info1    1971-01-01 BBB   
3 third      3 AAA    info1    1972-01-01 BBB   
4 first      1 CCC    info2    1970-01-02 DDD   
5 second     2 CCC    info2    1971-01-02 DDD   
6 third      3 CCC    info2    1972-01-02 DDD
```

I though it could work by writing a function that handles one of the "AAA_info2_BBB"-type columns at a time, and it seems to work using the following function

```
my_fun <- function(df, one_var) {

  # Get string from called column name
  one_var_char <- 
    enquo(one_var) %>%  
    { as.character(.)[2] }  

  # Split string across "_" and return character vector
  one_var_char_splitted <- 
    one_var_char %>% 
    { strsplit(., "_")[[1]] }

  new_one_var <- one_var_char_splitted[2]

  names(df)[names(df) == one_var_char] <- new_one_var

  df %>%
    select(new_one_var) %>% 
    data.frame(source = one_var_char_splitted[1],
               period = one_var_char_splitted[3] )
}
```

Which returns (as expected)

```
Ihave %>% 
  select(ID, group, AAA_info2_BBB) %>% 
  my_fun(AAA_info2_BBB)

       info2 source period
1 1970-01-01    AAA    BBB
2 1971-01-01    AAA    BBB
3 1972-01-01    AAA    BBB
```

But I cannot manage to "map" this function onto the `Ihave` data frame to produce the desired `Iwant`. I have tried several mixtures of `purrr::map`, without success. Is there a flaw in my approach? Have I missed something?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I would probably approach this problem by reshaping the dataset into a long format rather than looping through columns with `map()`.  For example, you could use `tidyr::gather()` to get your column names onto rows and then use `tidyr::separate()` to split the column of former column names into multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. It was actually my first idea as well. But is there a way to make this work while keeping the date formats?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not reproducing a problem with dates.  Post `gather()` things are still dates for me (I'm using tidyr 0.8.1 without loading the rest of the *tidyverse*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea as `gather` then `separate`, but just for the sake of variety here's a `data.table` method using `melt` and `tstrsplit`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Ihave)

melt(Ihave, c('ID', 'group'))[, 
  c('source', 'variable', 'period') := tstrsplit(variable, '_')]

#        ID group variable      value source period
# 1:  first     1    info2 1970-01-01    AAA    BBB
# 2: second     2    info2 1971-01-01    AAA    BBB
# 3:  third     3    info2 1972-01-01    AAA    BBB
# 4:  first     1    info3 1970-01-02    CCC    DDD
# 5: second     2    info3 1971-01-02    CCC    DDD
# 6:  third     3    info3 1972-01-02    CCC    DDD
```

Comment: I both like and hate the side-effect nature of dome of `data.table` functions. Is there a reason you use `setDT` instead of `as.data.table` with an assignment? (I'm not a DT user, keep telling myself I should learn it.)

Comment: In data.table parlance, all set* functions change their input by reference. That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory, which is as large as one column.

Comment: setDT converts lists (both named and unnamed) and data.frames to data.tables by reference. This feature was requested on Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy

Comment: I understand that most `data.table` functions have side-effect by-design: the in-place operations on frames can be really appealing and performant. My question was about `setDT` versus `as.data.table`. Notably, what is done under the hood for `as.data.table.default` just uses `setDT`, but `as.data.table.data.frame` does not. So is there a canonical reason why `setDT` is preferred over `as.data.table`? I can find no declaration of using one of the other in the [`data.table` wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki).

Comment: Perhaps a comment is not the best place for me to be asking this, though.

Comment: [It's been specifically asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41917887/3358272), in addition to the link you provided. I should have known better than to rabbit-hole this question (in a comment) with my own question. Sorry to bother!

Comment: No worries, thanks for the link. Hadn't seen that question

Answer (score 3):

I fashioned this before I saw @aosmith's comments, which is spot-on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Ihave %>%
  gather(source, value, -ID, -group) %>%
  separate(source, into = c("source", "variable", "period"), sep = "_")
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   ID     group source variable period value     
#   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <date>    
# 1 first      1 AAA    info2    BBB    1970-01-01
# 2 second     2 AAA    info2    BBB    1971-01-01
# 3 third      3 AAA    info2    BBB    1972-01-01
# 4 first      1 CCC    info3    DDD    1970-01-02
# 5 second     2 CCC    info3    DDD    1971-01-02
# 6 third      3 CCC    info3    DDD    1972-01-02
```

It relies on the number of `_`-separated fields being constant, ordered, and known. If the format never changes, you're good. Otherwise, you'll need to write something a little more specific/custom to deal with any variation.

You do not need to explicitly invoke `library(dplyr)` or `tidyr` if you are already loading `library(tidyverse)`. (I include them here in case (a) somebody comes along and is not explicitly loading all 25 packages, or (b) you thought you needed all of them but want to reduce load time by trimming unused packages.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort to remain inside the tidyverse, but I tried this (sorry I did not mention it in my post but I felt it was long enough) and look at what's happening to the date fields. Would you have a solution for this? Thans again though.

Comment: Not sure what happened in my copy/paste, I was not paying that close attention. I re-ran the code (no changes!) and the output is fixed. \*shrug\*