# How to identify the first and last occurrence across columns and record the position?

Tags: r

I would like to create two variables which identify the first and last occurrence across multiple columns. Each row is an individual. Each column is a repeated binary observation. The column names refer to ages (1,3,5,8,11).

Here is some data:

```
structure(list(T1 = c(1, 0, 1), T3 = c(1, 1, 1), T5 = c(0, 1, 
1), T8 = c(1, 1, 0), T11 = c(1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I'd like to create two variables, first and last, which record the number in the corresponding column (1,3,5,8, or 11) when an observation appeared first or last. So, for row 1, first=1; for row 2, first=3. I am not sure how to do this in wide format.

Comment: Please let me know if the solution posted below is your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
data.frame(first = sub("\\D+", "", names(df1)[max.col(df1, "first")]), 
            last = sub("\\D+", "", names(df1)[max.col(df1, "last")]))
#     first last
#1     1   11
#2     3   11
#3     1   11
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) names(x)[range(which(as.logical(x)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to melt this data to get it to format that `data.table` or `dplyr` can work with. It will also make it useful if one day you decide to use `SQL` for this.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[, id := 1:.N]
dt.t <- melt(dt, id.vars = "id", variable.name = "age")
res <- dt.t[value == 1, .(first.observed = min(as.character(age)),
                last.observed = max(as.character(age))), id]
res
#       id first.observed last.observed
# 1:  1             T1            T8
# 2:  2            T11            T8
# 3:  3            T11            T5
```

You did not have `id` column for individuals in your dataset, I have created one for this example.

Comment: Better use `setDT(dt)` instead of `dt <- data.table(dt)`, see [Convert a data frame to a data.table without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy) as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` option could be to create a column of `row_number()`, `gather` into long format, remove 0 rows and get `first` and `last` column for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -row) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  mutate(key = sub("T", "", key)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(first = first(key), 
            last = last(key)) %>%
  select(-row)

# first last 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 1     11   
#2 3     11   
#3 1     11
```

---

Base R approach using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(col~row, which(df == 1, arr.ind = TRUE), function(x) names(df)[range(x)])
```