# How to create a table from a dataframe in SparkR

Tags: sql, r, data-science, databricks

I am trying to find a way to convert a dataframe into a table to be used in another Databricks notebook. I cannot find any documentation regarding doing this in R.

Comment: Does `as.table` do it for you?

Comment: I will try that thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a data frame to a data.table without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345022/convert-a-data-frame-to-a-data-table-without-copy)

Comment: Can also create a temp table that can be accessed from another notebook. `createOrReplaceTempView(createDataFrame(df), "temp_df")`

Answer (score 0):

First, convert R dataframe to SparkR dataframe using `SparkR::createDataFrame(R_dataframe)`. Then use [saveAsTable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/saveAsTable.html) function to save as a permanent table - which can be accessed through other notebooks. `SparkR::createOrReplaceTempView` will not help if you try to access it from different notebook.

```
require(SparkR)
data1 <- createDataFrame(output)
saveAsTable(data1, tableName = "default.sample_table", source="parquet", mode="overwrite")
```

In the above code, `default` is some existing database name, under which a new table will get created having name as `sample_table`.